# 'Failed to create the 'Pages' library.' Content type not found in web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, error, publishing-site

When trying to create an Enterprise Search Center in SharePoint 2010 the following error occurred:

Event log messages:

> 05/15/2014 11:06:46.41     w3wp.exe (0x1350)                           0x1CF8  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         8fia    Exception   CreatePagesDocumentLibrary failed. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Content type '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39' not found in web '%YOURSITE%'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CommonUtilities.GetContentType(SPWeb web, SPContentTypeId contentTypeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreatePagesDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)   5ac502be-9db9-4ad4-8a72-8b4ae48ea2d9
>
> 05/15/2014 11:06:46.44     w3wp.exe (0x1350)                           0x1CF8  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 81eed5e0 "web content management", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", cbe1bb56 "microsoft.sharepoint.publishing", 0e0017e4 "14.0.6116.0", 4f1635ec "tue jan 17 20:01:00 2012", 000001c7 "000001c7", 00000040 "00000040", d229b6b2 "spexception:80131600", 38666961 "8fia"    5ac502be-9db9-4ad4-8a72-8b4ae48ea2d9
>
> 05/15/2014 11:06:46.45     w3wp.exe (0x1350)                           0x1CF8  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         4965    Critical    Event log message was: 'Failed to create the 'Pages' library.'. Exception was: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Content type '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39' not found in web '%YOURSITE%'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CommonUtilities.GetContentType(SPWeb web, SPContentTypeId contentTypeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreatePagesDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)' 5ac502be-9db9-4ad4-8a72-8b4ae48ea2d9
>
> 05/15/2014 11:06:46.48     w3wp.exe (0x1350)                           0x1CF8  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         75ot    Unexpected  Publishing Feature activation failed. Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to create the 'Pages' library. OriginalException: Content type '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39' not found in web '%YOURSITE%'. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Content type '0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39' not found in web '%YOURSITE%'.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CommonUtilities.GetContentType(SPWeb web, SPContentTypeId contentTypeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreatePagesDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---...   5ac502be-9db9-4ad4-8a72-8b4ae48ea2d9
>
> 05/15/2014 11:06:46.48*    w3wp.exe (0x1350)                           0x1CF8  Web Content Management          Publishing Provisioning         75ot    Unexpected  ...     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.CreatePagesDocumentLibrary(SPList approvalTaskList)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.AreaProvisioner.Provision()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__0()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.CultureUtility.RunWithCultureScope(CodeToRunWithCultureScope code)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.RunWithWebCulture(SPWeb web, CodeToRun webCultureDependentCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties).   5ac502be-9db9-4ad4-8a72-8b4ae48ea2d9

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to the Publishing features. To resolve the issue:

1. Go to Site Settings
2. Click Site collection features
3. Deactivate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' feature
4. Reactivate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' feature
5. Go back to Site Settings
6. Click Manage site features
7. Activate the 'SharePoint Server Publishing' feature

This resolved the problem for me.